# Regex to replace hashtags from array in text

Tags: node.js, regex

I try to replace text with keywords by hashtags and remove words used from array.

My array:

```
['Test', 'NodeJS', 'regex']
```

> Here, test with NodeJS to try regex !

Become:

> Here, #Test with #NodeJS to try #Regex !

Could you guide me on how to do this with NodeJS and a regex?

Comment: What if the word appears several times in the string, should only the first be transformed?

Comment: All keywords if possible...

Comment: OK, why do you want the elements to be deleted from the array? Do you want to do something with that array afterwards? Should elements be removed only when they occur?

Comment: Just to be sure: Should `test test test` become `#Test #Test #Test`?

Comment: Yes it's correct !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `reduce`, `new RegExp` and `replace` with a callback function (for marking a word as used):

```js
var tags = ['Test', 'NodeJS', 'notfound', 'regex']
var s = "Here, test with NodeJS to try regex !";

s = tags.reduce((acc, tag, i) => 
    acc.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + tag + "\\b", "gi"), () => {
        tags[i] = null;
        return "#" + tag;
    }), s);
tags = tags.filter(Boolean);
console.log(s);
console.log(tags);
```

If your array contains strings with special characters that need to be escaped, then first transform them like explained in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

If you only want to replace the *first* occurrence of a specific tag, then remove the "g" modifier.

Comment: That's almost it, it should be in the table, there are more tags that are not used. It will be perfect !

Comment: Updated my answer; hope I understood your intention.

Comment: You're great ! Thanks you very much!

Comment: Just a precision, with this code, the string can become : Désorm#AIs if I have a #AI hashtag with string "Désormais"...

Comment: @primax, indeed. I have now added break requirements in the regex to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks you very much, You helped me a lot!